# Add two mathematical expressions from user inputn

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to add two numbers in Python, where the first and second input can be a numerical expression ,consider:

```
a = int(input("enter first number"))   #numerical expression as input  
b = int(input("enter second number"))  #numerical expression as input  
c = (a+b) 
print(c)
```

I tried out:

```
x = int(input("enter first number:"))
y = int(input("enter first number:"))
z = (x+y)
print(x)
```

But it's not working, when I do:

```
enter first number:5
enter first number:6*9
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SACHIN/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    y=int(input("enter first number"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6*9'
```

Comment: unclear question. Are you trying to enter 25x98...for the second input?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can't call `int` on arbitrary strings.  If the input contains operators like `'/'` thenn you need to parse it somehow.

Comment: I think he wants to use the eval function in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=(input("enter first number"))
y=(input("enter first number"))
z=eval(x+"+"+"("+y+")")
print(z)
```

Comment: Using `eval` is a very (very) bad advice. But if you're already doing it, why not just `z = x + eval(y)`?

Comment: Oh and also try to only answer well-asked questions... It is not really clear what OP is trying to do nor what is wrong with that so it's not really possible to answer as well...

Comment: ok. Advise registered. To get back to your original comment. Making the x an int results in the TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' .  I could perhaps evaluate second operand and then add. But for simplicity sake leaving as is. Your advise on the bad choice of using eval is well taken.

Comment: Ok, you could do `z = x + int(eval(y))` but then what if the input is `25/78` which is a float? As I said - I wouldn't answer such question...